# toggle button class on click? c#

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I currently have a list that is generated in c# behind code. I have one onclick function that is sent by all buttons. What i would like to do is pass the object of the button when the click occurs so I can toggleClass for that specific button. Although I'm  sure there could be other ways to do it..here's my behind code

```
protected void createMenu(TreeView navTree) {

        foreach(TreeNode node in navTree.Nodes){

        HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
        li.Attributes.Add("class", "toggle");
        navMenu.Controls.Add(li);

        HtmlGenericControl anchor = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
        anchor.Attributes.Add("href", "javascript:navButtonClick();");
        anchor.InnerText = node.Text;

        li.Controls.Add(anchor);


        HtmlGenericControl ul = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");
        li.Controls.Add(ul);
        ul.Attributes.Add("class", "subnav"); 

        foreach (TreeNode childNode in node.ChildNodes) {

            HtmlGenericControl child_li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
            ul.Controls.Add(child_li);

            HtmlGenericControl childAnchor = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
            childAnchor.Attributes.Add("href", "#");
            childAnchor.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
            childAnchor.InnerText = childNode.Text;

            child_li.Controls.Add(childAnchor);

        }

        }
```

The output looks like this:

```
<div id="sidebar">
```

### Sites

```
  <li class="toggle-is-open"><a href=""javascript:navButtonClick();"">Stanislaus</a>
    <ul class="subnav">
       <li><a href="#" class="active">linnie<span class="quantity">7</span></a></li>
       <li><a href="#" class="active">tom<span class="quantity">7</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="toggle-is-open"><a href=""javascript:navButtonClick();">Merced</a>
     <ul class="subnav">
        <li><a href="#" class="active">emmanuel<span class="quantity">7</span></a></li>
     </ul>

</nav>
    </div>
```

so i basically need something like

```
function navButtonClick(buttonID){
navMenu.getbyElementID(buttonID).toggleClass("is-open")
```

}

Comment: Don't tell me you are attaching a li to menu and adding ul to that li and adding li  to ul! No wonder you ended up with the broken html that you have posted! You can look at the basics of html, [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp) is Unsorted list.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try something like that

```
$(".buttonID").attr(‘class’, ‘is-open’) ;
```

Comment: How do I pass the ID to the function?

Comment: Actually in as you are in an event I guess you could simply do that : this.attr('class','Is-open'). This would represent the element that called the event

Comment: would there be a way to call toggleClass with this?

Comment: Try "this.toggleclass("is-open")"

Comment: hmm, it doesnt seem to recognize what "this" is could i do something like this?  anchor.Attributes.Add("href","javascript:navButtonClick(this);");

Comment: No, just do it like that on your link : <a href="" onclick="navButtonClick();"> This will call your function when clicking on the link. And this will supposed to be initialized

Comment: hmm, doesnt seem to be working. Also, I have an alert function right below it that doesn't fire unless I comment it out

Comment: Yeah... I guess That is because you should use $(this) instead of just "this" Sry for the misunderstanding

Comment: Hmm, still not working. Which property could I use to try an alert showing the inner text? alert($(this).text) just so i can test if the object is correct